# How can i create different directories to support diffrent resolutions for Android in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have been trying to support multiple screen resolutions for Android, i have tried all the viewports but non of them fit my game well, my game is like Asteroids where the ship wraps around the world when it reaches the edge of the screen. if i use Fitviewport on some resolutions the ship wraps around before it reaches the edge of the screen and if use Fillviewport the ship goes out of the screen instead of wraping around, if i use Stretchviewport the game looks horrible the other viewports are not working well either, So i think the only solution for me would be to create diffrent assets for diffrent resolutions, now how  do i go about doing that?

Comment: Why not just scale every element, in proportion to the screen?

Answer (score 0):

try using ExtendViewPort and provide the minimum and maximum viewports your app should support. The maximum size will limit how much the world is extended and the minimum how much shrink

Comment: If i use ExtendViewport the assets look very large `private void setupCamera(){
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.position.set(Constants.CENTER_X, Constants.CENTER_Y, 0);
        viewport = new ExtendViewport(800,480,1920,1200,camera);
        }

       @Override
    public void resize (int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
    } `

Answer (score 0):

I've never used LibGDX, but it sounds like your problem is with different aspect ratios, not different resolutions.

So if I were you, I'd try Fillviewport, and then I'd calculate everything manually to make sure to reset the location of the ship (and any other objects) to the other side when it collides with the edge of the screen.

This is not super easy, so this is why a game like [PewPew](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jyaif.pewpew&hl=en) will use a square frame for its asteroids-mode instead.